# Finding the pdf of $Z=X-Y$ where $f(x,y)=x(x-y)/8$

Tags: probability

> Suppose the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is
>
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} x(x-y)/8&-x<y<x,0<x<2\\ 0&\text{otherwise}
>  \end{cases}$$
>
> Give the pdf of $Z=X-Y$

**My try:**

I first note that since the largest value $z$ can take on is $2x$ then the smallest value $x-z$ can take on is $-x$ and so
$$\{-x<y<x\} \cap \{y \geq x-z\} =  \{x-z \leq y < x\}$$

and so we have

$$\begin{align*}
F_Z(z)
&=P(Z\leq z)\\\\
&=P(X-Y\leq z)\\\\
&=P(Y\geq X-z)\\\\
&=\int_0^2\int_{-x}^x\mathbf{1}\{y \geq x-z\} f(x,y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}\\\\
&= \int_0^2\int_{x-z}^{x} f(x,y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}\\\\
&=\frac{z^2}{8}\end{align*}$$

But the support of $Z$ is $(0,4)$ so this is not a valid cdf. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the limits of your integration are incorrect. The support of $(X,Y)$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(2,2),(2,-2)$. Using this I got,

$$F_Z(z)=\int_{0}^{z/2}\int_{-x}^{x}f(x,y)dydx+\int_{z/2}^{2}\int_{x-z}^{x}f(x,y)dydx=\frac{z^4+2z^2(16-z^2)}{2^8}$$ for $0<z<4$, $F_Z(z)=0$ for $z\le 0$, $F_Z(z)=1$ for $z\ge 4$.

Comment: Could you please clarify why we need to split it up into these two cases?

Comment: We need to integrate over the quadrilateral formed by the lines $x=y,x=-y,x-y=z,x=2$. I split it up into a triangle and a parallelogram.